# Is there a package manager for D?

Tags: d, package-managers

I found [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), which looks useful, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't really want a build tool; what I really want is a package manager.

Other languages have similar tools:

- Python- easy_install or ppp
- JavaScript/NodeJS- npm
- Go- goinstall

I would like to have a single database of open-source D projects that can be integrated into a larger application with only a couple commands, such as (assuming dpack is the command):

```
# get source from database, run build script if there is one
dpack install some_package

# builds current package, grabbing dependencies as necessary
dpack build

# removes source (build will fail without it)
dpack remove
```

Is there anything like this for D? If not, I'll probably end up writing it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Please see the top rated answer about Dub. It is now the defacto package manager for D and will soon to be the official package manager which will be included with D compilers.

<del>There have been several attempts by various people and a lot of discussion.  The only one I know of that is actively being worked on is [Orbit](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/orbit) by Jacob Carlborg.</del>

Comment: I don't know. I've been wondering where he was at with it myself.

Comment: Regardless of its exact state, no one's generating packages for it, and there is no general repository of D packages for it, so it's not going to do what you want yet. At this point, it's the most likely candidate for an official package manager, but there's a good chance that it'll be a while before it's finished and actually actively used by the D community.

Comment: Then I guess I'll get to work on my own then. It will be a nice project to get familiar with the language anyway.

Comment: @he_the_great - My ideal package manager would be similar to NPM for node, which doesn't seem like the style that Orbit is using.

Answer (score 8):

I found this,

http://code.dlang.org/about

It distrubute something called DUB packages.

> DUB is s build tool for D projects with support for automatically retrieving dependencies and integrating them in the build process. The design emphasis is on maximum simplicity for simple projects, while providing the opportunity to customize things when needed.

Comment: This is definitely the default now. It seems like Dub will also be merged into the main compiler code with one of the next releases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's being actively worked on, but you could take a look at DSSS

> DSSS, the D Shared Software System, builds upon rebuild and intends to
>   create a standardized system for building, installing, configuring,
>   acquiring and using D software, licensed as Free and Open Source
>   Software under the MIT license:
>   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php . One notable
>   component of it is its net module, which provides an analogue to
>   Perl's CPAN or Ruby's Gems for the D programming language.

http://www.dsource.org/projects/dsss

Comment: I did see that, and it got me really excited, but I saw that the last modified date was something like 2007 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Some time has already passed since the original question (and answers) has been posted, but in late 2021 **DUB** (https://github.com/dlang/dub) **comes preinstalled with DMD** (the reference compiler), and there is a central repository of packages available at https://code.dlang.org/.

If you use other compilers (GDC, LDC etc.) you might still need to install DUB manually and use e.g. `dub --compiler=gdc ...`